# Split and prioritize Bootstrap's css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm interested to find out if there is a way to split and prioritize `Bootstrap`'s **css** components.

Let's say I need whole `Bootstrap` (~105Kb). It's clear that components like `Normalize`, `Typography`, `Grid system`, `Responsive utilities` should come immediately (in order to avoid FOUC or similar experience) and that components like `Tooltip`, `Glyphicons` and others may be loaded later (as the matter of fact, I'm planning deferred loading for these).

By looking at the [source](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master) I can see that there are `LESS` components (unfortunately I'm familiar with `SASS`), but I'm not sure what exactly to do/how to start?

---

**EDIT:**
the title and some parts of question may be misleading. I'm only interested in splitting Bootstrap's css into multiple css files and have control over that.

The 'prioritize' part is more related to making decisions about which components should come ASAP and which should not and mens of loading them - which is not what I'm asking.

Comment: Intersting question, although unless Bootstrap 3 was designed with modularisation from the outset you might be in for some painful work. Worth considering if the supposed performance benefits are worth it. I'd rather keep 1 gzipped request which will be cached and never transferred again.

Comment: @tmslnz but Google actually hates that and marks it as 'blocking resource above the fold'.

Comment: Then head to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ and chip away at it.

Comment: so sad that this question is 2 years old and has no answers, there must be a way in bootstrap to create chunks as needed